# Magento2 disable newsletter success mail

Tags: newsletter, newsletter-subscriber

I did google how to do it, I found one solution online
https://www.metagento.com/blog/magento-2-disable-newsletter-subscription-success-email

https://github.com/metagento/magento-2-disable-newsletter-success-email

however I don't know why I can't install, I did check the module status, it not showing in the list. even I follow from their website, still no success.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

can anyone tell me how to get this thing install?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using dependency injection that is `di.xml`
You need to compile you `di`

Try running the below command

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Answer (score 0):

Did composer throw any errors when you ran *composer require metagento/disable-newsletter-success-magento2*?

Make sure to run *composer update* after running that composer require command above, then try running the other commands:

- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
- php bin/magento cache:flush

Answer (score 0):

If you can't see installed module by `module:status` you can check in `config.php` file.

Still, you are not able to install module then there is an issue in the module.

There is one another module I have searched for disabling newsletter email [Disable newsletter mail](https://www.mageexchange.com/disable-newsletter-sign-up-emails-magento-2) install and check.

**Note:** I have not tested this extension.